# How to render dynamic HTML file in express without a template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an HTML file which has certain dependencies with it like a javaScript file and 2 css files and I want to use it on my express server. Unfortunately the page's functionality begins to break when I use

```
app.get("/stats", (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/comparator/index.html'));
})
```

I was thinking if there was any way I can still display it? If there's not what's the quickest way to change the HTML file to a template engine file?

Comment: As I know `HTML` serves static file and a template engine is used to serve the dynamic content. To serve dynamic file you need to use a template engines like `ejs`, `handlebars` or you can choose any front-end frameworks like `Angular' `react'.

Comment: The thing is the file seems to break when I link it in the above mentioned way. I don't understand why as it has it's own javaScript, CSS files

Comment: does it render HTML file or not?

Comment: It does but not the same way it does if I open the HTML file locally from it's source folder. The alignment of everything is changed and it is essentially not functioning.

Comment: Maybe the resources which `comparator/index.html` includes are not being downloaded. Do you see any errors in console?